# Несколько окон JFrame

Tags: java, swing, jframe

Здравствуйте.
С Java работаю только несколько дней, поэтому возник вопрос.

Есть 2 формы. Мне нужно из одной формы открыть другую. При этом ту, с которой вызывалась другая форма, нужно скрыть. И так же с другой формы.

Я делаю так:
Есть 2 файла: Form1.java и Form2.java.

Form1.java

Код по нажатию кнопки

```
Form2 form2 = new Form2();              
form2.setVisible(true);
frame.setVisible(false);
```

Form2.java

Код по нажатию кнопки

```
Form1 form1 = new Form1();
form1.setVisible(true);
frame2.setVisible(false);
```

В общем то с 1 формы 2 вызывается и форма 1 скрывается. Но если возвращаться с 2 к 1 форме, то 2 уже не скрывается. Т.е. первый раз код выполняется нормально и форма скрывается, а все последующие разы уже нет.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Думаю, здесь имеет смысл использовать вспомогательный класс, который займется переключением окон. Например.

**FormManager.java**

```
public interface FormManager {
  void toggleForms();
}
```

**Main.java**

```
public class Main implements FormManager {
private JFrame form1;
private JFrame form2;

public static void main(String... args) {
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            new Main();
        }
    });
}

public Main() {
    form1 = new Form1(this);
    form2 = new Form2(this);
    form1.setVisible(true);
}


@Override
public void toggleForms() {
    form1.setVisible(!form1.isVisible());
    form2.setVisible(!form2.isVisible());
}
}
```

**Form1.java**

```
public class Form1 extends JFrame {
private final FormManager manager;

public Form1(final FormManager manager) {
    this.manager = manager;

    setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    setPreferredSize(new Dimension(200,100));
    add(new JButton("form2") {{
        addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                manager.toggleForms();
            }
        });
    }});
    pack();
}

}
```

Иными словами, Вы заранее создаете 2 формы (form1 и form2 в Main классе), видимость которых переключаете по клику на соответствующие кнопки. В этой реализации классы форм не связаны между собой и ничего не знают о существовании друг друга, но у них есть ссылка на общий управляющий класс менеджера, который контролирует видимость обеих форм. Такой подход позволяет избежать массы проблем в больших приложениях.